# Metaclass Inheritance

Tags: python, metaclass

Hi all python programmer, I would like to ask about metaclass as below:

```
class MyMeta(type):
        pass

class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
        pass

class MySubclass(metaclass=MyClass):
       pass

test1 = MySubclass()

print(test1)
```

why I cannot use class aa as a metaclass of class aaa?

Comment: Class names: concatenated words each starting with upper case. I reform the tile and class names

Answer (score 0):

Because your `subclass (object())` takes no parameters and if you pass parameter on to it, it throws an error.

you simply write your code like below:

```
class MyMeta(type):
        pass

class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta):
        pass

class MySubclass(MyClass):
        pass

test1 = MySubclass()

print(test1)
```

For additional information, you can check this link [pyhthon-metaclasses](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-metaclasses)

Comment: I think because of metaclass is only inherite from type only .